# Rails model with multipe values for a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Movie.  That can have multiple Showtimes.  Each Showtime is a pair of start and end times.  Movies get saved in the database.

So although a Movie might have_many Showtimes, does that really need to be a model, or just a class, or some kind of custom tuple-like type?

I have seen where you can have a field with an array of values, but this would not be basic values as each value is a pair of times.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showtimes should be a model, yes. Here are a few reasons:

- Most relational databases don't natively support a tuple or array type.
- What if you want to query movies occurring at a particular time? This would be difficult to do with a custom field, but would be relatively trivial with a separate table.
- Most importantly, it enables better flexibility and extensibility through decreased coupling. For instance, does a showtime always exist exclusively to a movie? What if you want to extend your schema to add theatres where each theatre has many showtimes?

Comment: Yes I see the advantages, was just unsure if that was the only or best route to take, each showtime belongs to only the specific movie/theater though, would not want multiple using the same in case only one needed to change